# What is the origin of the suffix ING?

Tags: etymology

Which language is the origin of the suffix [ING](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ing.html)? Wiktionary doesn't mention its etymology and I can't find a language with a similar suffix.

De kiu lingvo venas la sufikso [ING](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ing.html)? Vikivortaro ne mencias ĝian etimologion kaj mi ne povas trovi lingvon kun simila sufikso.

Comment: La vorto _"fitting"_ por (nespecifa) ingo (de lampo) povus esti origino, kvankam mi ne havas ian bazon pri tio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Cherpillod (*Konciza Etimologia Vortaro*, p. 199) and Vilborg (*Etimologia Vortaro de Esperanto, S-Z*, p. 161) consent that *-ing-* stems from the German suffix *-ling* (masc.), which has a very broad meaning (*Flüchtling* 'refugee', *Liebling* 'darling', in Esperanto it in most cases would be *-ul(et)o*) and in the word *Fingerling* 'finger stall' exactly matches Esperanto *fingr/ing/o*.

So probably *-ing* was extracted (by conscious or unconscious metanalysis) from the single German word *Fingerling*.